# TYPO3 - TypoScript add Link Parameters

Tags: typo3, typoscript

is it possible to add extra link parameters only to the first menu item (menu-itemfirst)

```
item1
<div class="menu-itemfirst">
<a onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="planner/">planner</a></div>
item2
<div class="menu-item">
<a onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="concept/">Concept</a>
</div>
etc….
```

it should look like this…

```
item1
<div class="menu-itemfirst">
<a onfocus="blurLink(this);" href=„int/kdb/eng/planner/">planner</a></div>
item2
<div class="menu-item">
<a onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="concept/">Concept</a>
</div>
etc….
```

add the parameters: int/kdb (static) and eng (dynamic, the language key)

My TS:

```
lib.mainNavigation = HMENU
    lib.mainNavigation {
      special = 
      excludeUidList = 
      1 = TMENU
      1 {

        noBlur = 0
        NO {
          allWrap = <div class="menu-itemfirst"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div> || <div class="menu-item"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div> || <div class="menu-item"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div>
          stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT {

            allWrap = <div class="menu-itemfirst-act" style="padding-left:0;"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div> || <div class="menu-item-act"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div> || <div class="menu-item-act"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div>
          stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
       }    


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your menu in two parts and use **COA**. E.g. something, like this:

```
lib.mainNavigation = COA
lib.mainNavigation.10 = HMENU
lib.mainNavigation.10 {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    maxItems = 1
    NO {
      allWrap = <div class="menu-itemfirst"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div>
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap.wrap = <a onfocus="blurLink(this);" href="int/kdb/{$config.language}/planner/">|</a>
    }

    ACT = 1
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.allWrap = <div class="menu-itemfirst-act" style="padding-left:0;"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div>
  }
}

lib.mainNavigation.20 = HMENU
lib.mainNavigation.20 {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    noBlur = 0
    begin = 2
    NO {
      allWrap = <div class="menu-item"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div>
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    }

    ACT = 1
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.allWrap = <div class="menu-item-act"> | </div><div class="menuline"></div>
  }
}
```

Please, note, that you need to have then a *constant* with name **config.language**, which corresponds to your language mapping and changes within language TS consitions. Sure, you may change the name to more suitable, but then don't forget to change it in TS of the menu.

Also I didn't test this code, but you should get an idea, what to do.